Can you use OpenRewrite with Bazel?
I see instructions for using OpenRewrite with maven and gradle. Are there equivalent instructions for using it in a bazel-based monorepo?

A github codesearch gives some indication there are at least enum values for bazel, but https://github.com/openrewrite/rules_rewrite is impressively empty.

Moderne documentation seems to mention bazel much more…

Bazel is supported through the Moderne CLI and Moderne Platform, as part of our offerings at Moderne - the company behind OpenRewrite. We've mostly seen Bazel used for mono repos; repositories where the LST model is too large to keep in memory, and thus benefits most from the LST serialization unique to Moderne.
We had a similar question reach us through our public Slack and are exploring a collaboration there; perhaps you'd like to chime in there to get updates on any new developments.

As a quick follow up: We're also going to make this part of the documentation going forward.
